# Find the largest rectangle with no repeated elements

Tags: c, algorithm

Find the max size of rectangular contiguous submatrix of unique (i.e. non repeated within a given submatrix) element.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should set a maximum value to 0. Iterate the rows of the matrix and if they are not repeating (whatever that means), compare its size to the maximum. If it is bigger, then store the new maximum value and use that for further iterations. In case you found a new maximum, store whatever you need to store. So, the algorithm looks like this:

```
maximum <- 0
for all rows as row
    if (row is not repeating) then
        if (row rectangle size > maximum) then
            maximum <- new maximum
            store whatever you need to store
        end if
    end if
end for
```

Note, that if you do not have further information, then it is pointless to do a binary search, since you will have to check the size of each rectangle. If you have further knowledge about your rectangles, then the algorithm might be optimized.

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer solved the problem or guided you to the solution, then you can accept the answer, so people in the future will know that the problem is solvable and this is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

A first idea (recursion): Maybe identify pairs in the whole array, this will identify constraints to respect. If there is a value *v* at both positions x0,y0 and x1,y1 then you cannot have a rectangle containing these positions, so this will let you construct some possible rectangles from these values and recurse on them?

Another one (dynamic programming): start with elementary arrays (size 1x1) and try to merge them respecting the constraint?